# Listar arquivos em diretorio com ajax

Tags: php, ajax

É possivel listar os arquivos de um diretorio com ajax e php?
Fiz uma pesquisa mas não encontro essa combinação!

```
$path = "/home/projetoc/public_html/filemanagerarquiv/files/";
$diretorio = dir($path);    
echo "Lista de Arquivos do diretório '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";    
while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
  echo "<a href='".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";
}
$diretorio -> close();
```

Comment: Sim é possível! a lógica fica no php e no final ele pode mantar um json para o javascript exibir ou manipular.

Comment: E como faria essa listagem com ajax. Atualizei a pergunta!

Comment: No lugar do echo, faça uma atribuição em um array com o link, depois do while mande um `echo json_encode($arrayDeLinks);`. AI no javascript vc manipula o json como achar melhor, só para testar de um `console.log(data)`, data é variável retornada no ajax

Comment: Gere um array com os diretórios e converta em json, depois é só manipular os dados com Ajax.